# How to show divs progressively with one function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with three div and one button. div2 and div3 are hidden, and div1 is shown from the beginning. What I want to do is that, when you press the button, div 2 appears below div 1, and then you press the button again, div 3 appears below div 1 and 2. What I have at the moment is this:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block;">
   Some stuff...
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
   Some stuff...
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none;">
   Some stuff...
</div>

<a><img id="button" src="img/button.png" onclick="myFunc()" /></a>
```

And the javascript:

```
function myFunc() {
    var d2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    var d3 = document.getElementById("div3");

    if ( d2.style.display == "none" ) {
        d2.style.display = "block";
    }

    if ( d2.style.display == "block" ) {
        d3.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

This is what I've got, but it displays div2 and div3 at the same time. Any idea on how to do it will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean `function myFunc() {`? Because what you have written won't work.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Silly mistake, I will edit it right now, in my code I have it, but writing it here I left it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need a counter variable

```
var count = 0;
function myFunc() {
  count += 1;
  var d2 = document.getElementById("div2"),
      d3 = document.getElementById("div3");

  if (count === 1) {
    if (d2.style.display == "none") {
      d2.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  if (count === 2) {
    if (d3.style.display == "none") {
      d3.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's just what I was missing!

Comment: This works but I think it's bad design. First, your code needs a global variable; then, it's tightly coupled to the IDs of the HTML, and then it doesn't work if you plan to add new divs. But I guess it works.... My solution works in one line of code, no global, and no problem when you need to add new divs.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the HTML and use classes, like this

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block;">
   Some stuff...
</div>

<div class="divMagic" id="div2" style="display:none;">
   Some stuff...
</div>

<div class="divMagic" id="div3" style="display:none;">
   Some stuff...
</div>

<a><img id="button" src="img/button.png" onclick="myFunc()" /></a>
```

That way, you can add more divs and it'll still work. And then for the jQuery code, something like this:

```
function myFunc() {

   $('body').find('.divMagic').filter(':hidden').eq(0).show();
}
```

I would recommend changing $('body') for the container of the divs.

Comment: OP did not specify jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're down to use a jquery plugin, I created a plugin for this very need:
https://github.com/fillswitch/Jquery-Sequential-Animations

It lets you cycle over a jquery collection and animate each one sequentially, one after another.

Answer (score 0):

div1 is the div you press to expand div2. The content list under div 2 is of course what you will see once it is expanded.

The script shows once the document is loaded you will be able to click the div and it will slide up or down when you click. I haven't made anything to control the speed.

Jquery is required for this.

```
<div id="div1" style="cursor:pointer;">
EXPANDING COLLAPSING DIV
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
content<br />
content

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").click(function(){
    $("#div2").slideToggle();

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Consider adding some text explaining what your code does.

Comment: Also, the OP didn't specify that jQuery was acceptable, so consider rewriting your answer so it doesn't require it, or call it out explicitly as a dependency of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or, try a more object-oriented approach, and abstract the "visibility" into CSS classes rather than inline styles. More semantic and maintainable code, and easier to understand when rendered on the page.

**[(DEMO)](http://jsbin.com/lopuq/1/edit)**

**Revised HTML:**

```
  <!-- First div is visible initially -->
  <div class="progressive visible">
    Some stuff...
  </div>

  <div class="progressive">
    Some stuff...
  </div>

  <div class="progressive">
    Some stuff...
  </div>

  <!-- An ID of 'button' isn't very descriptive -->
  <a><img id="displayNextButton" src="img/button.png" /></a>
```

**New CSS:**

```
.progressive {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

**Revised JavaScript:**

```
function ProgressiveDisplayer() {
  this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName('progressive');
  this.currentlyVisible = 0;
}

ProgressiveDisplayer.prototype.displayNext = function() {
  if (this.currentlyVisible < this.elements.length - 1) {
    this.currentlyVisible++;
    this.elements[this.currentlyVisible].className += ' visible';
  }
}

var progressiveDisplayer = new ProgressiveDisplayer();

var displayNextButton = document.getElementById('displayNextButton');

displayNextButton.addEventListener('click', function() { progressiveDisplayer.displayNext(); });
```

Answer (score -1):

Either make that an if else instead of if if or better yet add a counter and the value of the counter gets appended to make the ID of the div e.g 'div' + counter

Comment: It sounds like you have a constructive suggestion, but it is difficult to fully comprehend your answer. Please expand your answer by including a code sample or expanding your explanation.